# Smooth zooming and rendering with PDFRenderer

Tags: android, pdf, rendering

I've been looking around for a good free solution for rendering PDF's on Xamarin.Android and eventually fell back to the [PDFRenderer API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfRenderer.html) that has been available since Lollipop.

Now what I want to achieve is smooth zooming/scaling while also rendering in a good quality, when zooming in. I can see that many apps have achieved this and I was wondering how they were able to do it properly. I'm currently calculating the zoom and then rendering to a bitmap by using the PDFRenderer.Page.render()-method giving it the drawMatrix of the imageView.

EDIT: My question really is that I don't understand how to use the rect and matrix parameters correctly to show the right bitmap on screen and can't find any examples using these with zoom.

Comment: Have you tried both the render mode vales(RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY,RENDER_MODE_FOR_PRINT), if that also does not work try setting scale value manually

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have been more specific about my issue. I've updated the question.

Comment: most of the apps use this https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer to render pdf as it has all the features integrated and it's backward compatible from API 11

Comment: @war_Hero couldn't find any Xamarin binding for it and I failed to do it myself :(

Comment: there is one last option left, you can open it in browser(webview) ? i can help you, in that you can zoom and do all that

Comment: what do say, is it ok to open it via a browser within app